# How is כֹּרֵת בְּרִית interpreted as "make" instead of "cut"?

Tags: language, parashat-ki-tisa, covenant

> וַיֹּאמֶר הִנֵּה אָנֹכִי **כֹּרֵת** בְּרִית נֶגֶד ([Exodus 34:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.34.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Targum%20Jerusalem&lang2=he))

And Targum translates similarly:

> "וַאֲמַר הָא אֲנָא **גְזַר** קְיַם"

Why כֹּרֵת relatively to the covenant end up being interpreted as "making" when it has always been used in the Tanakh in a sense of cutting off?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Israel and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: For example in English, you "cut" a check ...

Comment: I don’t understand the close votes. Surely this is Hebrew language as pertains to Judaism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rashi to Genesis 15:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Genesis.15.10.1?lang=bi) explains that it was the custom of those making a covenant to split an animal into pieces, and to then pass between the pieces.

Rashi also refers us to [Jeremiah 34:18-19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jeremiah.34.18?lang=bi) where this practice is explicitly mentioned:

> וְנָתַתִּי אֶת־הָאֲנָשִׁים הָעֹבְרִים אֶת־בְּרִתִי אֲשֶׁר לֹא־הֵקִימוּ אֶת־דִּבְרֵי הַבְּרִית אֲשֶׁר כָּרְתוּ לְפָנָי **הָעֵגֶל אֲשֶׁר כָּרְתוּ לִשְׁנַיִם וַיַּעַבְרוּ בֵּין בְּתָרָיו**׃
>
> I will make the men who violated My covenant, who did not fulfill the terms of the covenant which they made before Me, [like] **the calf which they cut in two so as to pass between the halves**.

Thus, idiomatically one talks of “cutting” a covenant, referencing the old practice of cutting up an animal as a way of binding the parties to the covenant.

Comment: And Brit bein habesarim

Comment: You nailed it with the exact quote!

Comment: But Interestingly, what's the rationale for this the ancient tradition? Why G-d did it to Avraham - it seems pagan to me.

Comment: @AlBerko they say in the name of the gra on sefer yetzirah that it is to show that in order to properly enter into a bond with another person, you must cut off something from yourself

Comment: @MosheSteinberg A noble idea, and you cut what... fingernails? hair? oh, animals! Does it mean like בל תשחית and you're sorry to waste the meat?

Comment: @AlBerko more of a metaphorical cutting off from oneself, perhaps giving up some of one's ego

Comment: @MosheSteinberg where does it say that the animals being cut must belong or must have been paid for, by one of the covenanting parties? For example, did Abraham own the animals that Hashem cut into two?

Comment: @Joel-K where does it say that the animals being cut must belong or must have been paid for, by one of the covenanting parties? For example, did Abraham own the animals that Hashem cut into two?

Comment: @ninamag I have no idea if that is a requirement

Comment: @JoelK surely one can not use animals stolen or animals not belonging to either party, no? If two people, say Abraham and Abimelech, were making a covenant with each other, then the animals would belong to either party.

Comment: @ninamag I have no idea. Maybe an animal borrowed for the purpose with the understanding that it would be cut up and returned to the owner afterwards would be fine.