# Different language with regards to establishing Bris

Tags: words, covenant

Throughout Chumash, there are a few different terms that are used to describe, broadly, the "establishing" of a Bris. Those words are כורת, והקמותי, and והיה. What are the different connotations of these words and why are they used in different places?

I feel as if this is something that Malbim would comment on, but alas, I can't seem to find him discussing it.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100491/how-is-%d7%9b%d6%bc%d6%b9%d7%a8%d6%b5%d7%aa-%d7%91%d6%bc%d6%b0%d7%a8%d6%b4%d7%99%d7%aa-interpreted-as-make-instead-of-cut

Answer (score 1):

כורת is used to mean the original making of the bris. והקמותי refers to the fulfillment of the bris. והיה refers to the existence of the bris.

Comment: Can you support your claims?

Comment: See the verse quoted here. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100491/how-is-%d7%9b%d6%bc%d6%b9%d7%a8%d6%b5%d7%aa-%d7%91%d6%bc%d6%b0%d7%a8%d6%b4%d7%99%d7%aa-interpreted-as-make-instead-of-cut?noredirect=1&lq=1 It is also the simple meaning of והקמותי and והיה in other contexts.